# Are getters bad for performance in Java?

Tags: java, performance, encapsulation

Given the following two code options, is there any performance benefit (over a very large scale or a long period of time) of the second over the first?

**Option 1**

```
private Map<Long, Animal> animals = ...;
public Map<Long, Animal> getAnimals() {
    return animals;
}

public void useAnimals() {
    for (int i=0; i < SOME_LARGE_NUMBER; i++) {
        Animal animal = getAnimals().get(id);
    }
    // Many many calls to getAnimals() are made...
}
```

**Option 2 - no getter**

```
private Map<Long, Animal> animals = ...;

public void useAnimals() {
    for (int i=0; i < SOME_NUMBER; i++) {
        Animal animal = animals.get(id);
    }
    // No method calls made
}
```

If it is bad for performance, why, and how should I determine whether it is worth mitigating?

And, would storing the result of `getAnimals()` as a local provide a benefit...

- if `SOME_NUMBER` is hundreds or thousands?
- if `SOME_NUMBER` is only in the order of magnitude of 10?

---

**Note**: I previously said "encapsulation".  I changed it to "getter" because the purpose is actually not that the field can't be modified but that it can't be reassigned.  The encapsulation is simply to remove responsibility for assignment from subclasses.

Comment: Why not benchmark the two and find out for yourself?

Comment: What is `id`, and is there any relationship between it and the loop variable `i`?

Comment: @Mike I intended there to be no relationship, but given that that part of the code is not changing, it should be irrelevant.

Comment: Note, "Option 1" is not encapsulation at all unless `getAnimals` returns a *copy* of the map, or a read-only wrapper around it.  If it returns the map itself, callers can modify the map (and thus, the object's internal state) at will.  Even then, though...is there a reason outsiders need that map?  If so, you're probably not encapsulating enough.

Comment: @cHao The "encapuslation" is merely around assignment, not around changing state, though, to reduce confusion I've removed the term from the question.

Comment: You might want to make `animals` final,  it makes it clear the fields shouldn't change, and it can help performance too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely JVM will inline `getAnimals()` invocation in tight loop effectively falling back to *Option 1*. So don't bother, this is really a micro (nano?) optimization.

Another thing is migrating from field access to local variable. This sounds good since instead of traversing through `this` reference every time you always have a reference on the stack (two memory accesses vs. one). However I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that since `animals` is private and non-`volatile` again JVM will perform this optimization for you at runtime.

Comment: This is definitely what I wanted to know.  Great answer, thanks.  Is there somewhere where I can learn more about stack/reference optimization?  I would like to understand how/why access modifiers affect such optimizations so I can code appropriately.

Comment: @Renesis you are missing the point, none of this matters with the JIT, it does it all silently in the background way better than you ever could. You might even keep it from doing other optomizations by trying to second guess the JIT. Write code that is sensible and maintainable, let the compiler and the JIT take care of this **sub-micro** performance issues. If you are so concerned about such tiny implementation details that may change from version to version go code in C.

Comment: @Jarrod When Tomasz says "since `animals` is private and non-volatile" I assume he means something by that - I'd like to know what that means and make sure I know how to write optimized code when otherwise I might not have any (strong) reason to choose one or the other.  You are making a lot of assumptions about my development that you really don't have the information to be making.

Comment: @Renesis - you still miss my point, you don't worry about this level of optimization when writing Java code regardless of what you are writing, if you are writing something that this kind of **sub-micro** optimization that is very very implementation dependent is critical, then Java isn't probably the right environment for your program. the **assumptions** he is making about the JVM are just that as well, these details change constantly. What might save a few single digit nano-seconds in 1.6.084 might cost you more in 1.6.085, **you can't do a better job than the compiler/JIT**

Comment: @Jarrod You are missing my point.  You *know* that too many method calls that all return the same value can [increase load significantly](http://blog.grovehillsoftware.com/2009/05/visualvm-and-cutting-method-calls-by.html).  Making your code not repeat those actions is standard optimization practice -- I'm wondering at what point those calls don't matter.  I don't *think* that returning a single class member should matter, but I want to be sure that assumption has been challenged -- that's why I ask the question.

Comment: @NickC: You might have misunderstood the example you linked. There the `isSupported` method possibly did some real work or maybe was too complicated for the JIT to be able to optimize it away. In case of trivial getters, there's nothing to gain. To explain `non-volatile`: The compiler must not assume anything about volatile fields, even when computing `a-a` it must make two memory accesses rather then simply return zero. Concerning `private` I'm not sure what assumptions the compiler does - in theory it's clear, but there's reflection, too.

Answer (score 5):

The second snippet is **more** encapsulated than the first one. The first one gives access to the internal map to anyone, whereas the second keeps it encapsulated in the class.

Both will lead to comparable performance.

EDIT: since you change the question, I'll also change the answer.

If you go through a getter, and the getter is not final, it means that subclasses may return another map than the one you hold in the class. Choose whether you want your method to operate on the subclass's map or on the class's map. Both could be acceptable, depending on the context.

Anyway, suppose your subclass always makes a defensive copy of the map, you'll end up having many copies if you don't cache the result of the getter in a local variable of `useAnimals`. It might be required to always work on the latest value of the subclass's map, but I doubt it's the case.

If there is no subclass, or the subclass doesn't override the method, or override it by always returning the same map, both will lead to comparable performance and you shouldn't care about it.

Comment: I apologize for my confusing use of the word encapsulation.  As this is an abbreviated example, I combined into one snippet what is actually from a parent class (the getter) and a sub class (the user).

Answer (score 3):

Have you profiled this to see if it matter, for a modern JIT I would **guess** it would get optomized away, especially if `animals` was marked `final` but there is nothing stopping you from testing this yourself.

Either way, I am 100% this would **NEVER** be your bottle neck in an application.

Answer (score -3):

Well, I don't think that JVM will inline the function call. So probably it may affect performance. The better way is to create local variable and assign class field animals to it.

Comment: Modern JIT's do [very aggressive inlining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719581/how-can-java-inline-over-virtual-function-boundaries).  Why do you think the example can't be inlined?

Comment: Frankly I did not know about Java inlining